# How to run my Python script with Anaconda environment in crontab?

Tags: scripts, python, cron, anaconda

I want to schedule a task with crontab to run a python file in a specific anaconda environment every day at a certain time. I have a python script to do so.

The python script runs if I just execute it with `python h.py` in the anaconda environment in terminal. `h.py` is in the home directory.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and I haven't refreshed or installed any new cron or crontab

I have tried the following commands to get it work but they just do nothing (the result should be a folder and it is clearly not has been created)

```
crontab -e
```

**Inside the crontab:**

```
#[long descriptional text]
...
53 13 * * * cd /home/ && /home/user/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python h.py
```

This also does nothing: no error message

I have also tried the following:

```
32 14 * * * cd /home/Documents && /home/user/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python h.py
```

and

```
34 14 * * * cd /home/Documents && /home/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python h.py 2>&1
```

From [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64470729/10270590).

[This answer on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572951/400960)  did not work with normal anaconda.

I have also read the following solutions but nothing has worked.

- [How can I run a Python script using Anaconda from the command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/300128/how-can-i-run-a-python-script-using-anaconda-from-the-command-line)
- [Crontab service file not found despite installed and configured crontab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/574085/crontab-service-file-not-found-despite-installed-and-configured-crontab)
- [Crontab doesnt run python script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021622/crontab-doesnt-run-python-script)
- [Execute Python script via crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727935/execute-python-script-via-crontab)
- [Crontab Python script does not run with Anaconda on Linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65904501/crontab-python-script-does-not-run-with-anaconda-on-linux-server)

One thing I've thought of but not tried is installing a daemon for crontab as is recommended [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1048365/984498), but I could not find cronie to install for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!! Give .sh file permission to run `chmod u+x my_shell_file_name.sh`

If the Python file only need python (not other library)
`56 16 * * * /home/MY_ACTUAL_USERNAME/anaconda3/envs/rapids/bin/python /home/MY_ACTUAL_USERNAME/Documents/h.py`

If Python file requires other python libraries that are in the anaconda environment:

- create a SHELL script

  ```
  nano my_shell_file_name.sh
  ```
- Example of what should be inside the file

  ```bsh
  #!/bin/bash
  #conda activate rapids WRONG
  source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate MY_ANACONDA_ENVIRONMENT_NAME #correct
  #python Documents/my_python_file_name.py WRONG SEPARATLY GO TO FOLER WHTAN EXECUTE EITH python
  cd ~/Documents/folder_where_python_file_is/ #correct
  python my_python_file_name.py #correct
  conda deactivate
  ```
- start up crontab with

  ```
  crontab -e
  ```
- example of what you can add to the end of this crontab file

  ```
  43 21 * * * /home/MY_ACTUAL_USERNAME/my_sehell_file_name.sh
  ```